# breakdates in strucchange gives float instead of date

Tags: r

I want to detect breakpoints in a dataset and using strucchange library.
Dataset as timeseries object made by xts as below:

```
           [,1]
2009-12-18  145
2010-01-08  100
2010-02-09  120
2010-03-02  150
2010-03-09  110
2010-03-23  180
2010-03-30  120
2010-04-06  135
2010-05-11  150
2010-05-25  155
2010-06-01   90
```

I using code below to detect breakdates but it gives me floats(double in r) as breakdates.

```
bp_ts <- breakpoints(duration ~ 1, breaks = 2)
summary(bp_ts)
```

The output is:

```
Corresponding to breakdates:
   m = 1   0.168604651162791                  
   m = 2   0.145348837209302 0.372093023255814
```

I want to output to be as date:

The output should be:

```
Corresponding to breakdates:
   m = 1   2010-03-23                 
   m = 2   2010-03-23 2010-05-11
```

I could not understand why dates become floats after breakpoints function application.

from now big thanks :)